# Formatting a parameter within an expression in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I am working with SQL Server Reporting Service. I need to change the colour of a parameter used with in an expression. I don't want to change the colour of the entire expression hence can you please let me know the best way to do this.

```
="Population Statistics for"  + Parameters!TotalPatientCntInPractice.Label
```

I would just like to change the colour of `Parameters!TotalPatientCntInPractice.Label`

Comment: could you not just use a seperate textbox?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have SSRS 2008 or above, you will need to set up multiple **placeholders** in your textbox.

See [Formatting Text and Placeholders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207048%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

> Right-click anywhere in the text box and select Insert Placeholder. In
>   the Placeholder Properties dialog box, you can specify an expression
>   as the value of your placeholder.

These allow you to have separate text sections in one textbox.

Once you have these placeholders set up in your textbox, you can apply different formatting to each placeholder, including a different colour to the placeholder which holds your parameter label expression.

If your using 2005 or below, your only really option will be to use two textboxes as suggested by @Yakyb in the comments.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring to use another style sheet as in the following tutorial?
http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s296/css-parameters.htm

Then style .TotalPatientCntInPractice.Label from there...

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Besides other options, You can continue to your single place holder and enclose the text you want to be set in specific color inside HTML  tag with Color attribute set to whatever color your like. You need to tell RS to Interpret HTML tags as styles. This causes the field to be evaluated as HTML. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627491(v=sql.100).aspx